# Do while loop not working with prompt. Javascript

Tags: javascript, do-while, prompt

I'm using JS Bin website to write this.

the loop fires only once when I give a bad (numeric) input :

```
function isInputLeapYear()
{
    var year = -1;

    var inputOk = true;

    do{
       year = prompt("Please enter a year to check if it is a leap year \ninput year between 0-9999");

       if(year < 0 || 9999 < year) // check input
       {
         inputOk = false;
         alert("\""+year+"\" is not a good year. \nThe input needs to be between 0-9999");              
       };


    }while(inputOk === false);


  ....
}
```

Comment: The `prompt` function returns a `string`, not a `number`. You may take a look at the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

Comment: You need to add an `else { inputOk = true; }`, otherwise your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is right .use parseInt function. year = parseInt(input) .

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It may return a string, but when strings are compared to numbers with `<` they are type coerced to numbers. So that part is fine.

Comment: While explicitly converting to number as @DarinDimitrov suggests would be *good*, it's not the problem. `<` will convert `year` to number when the other operand is a number (as is the case above).

Answer (score -2):

Move the the var `inoutOK = true` into the loop that way it resets before prompting again.

```
function isInputLeapYear()
{
   var year = -1;

   do {
       var inputOk = true;
       year = prompt("Please enter a year to check if it is a leap year \ninput year between 0-9999");

       if(year < 0 || 9999 < year) // check input
       {
          inputOk = false;
          alert("\""+year+"\" is not a good year. \nThe input needs to be between 0-9999");              
       };


    } while(inputOk === false);


  ....
}
```

Comment: Code dumps are not useful answers. Say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks did not know that. I edited the answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
    function isInputLeapYear()
    {
        var year = -1;

        var inputOk = false;

        do{
           year = prompt("Please enter a year to check if it is a leap year \ninput year between 0-9999");

           if(year > 0 && 9999 > year) // check input
           {
             inputOk = True;



           else
{
alert("\""+year+"\" is not a good year. \nThe input needs to be between 0-9999"); 
}  
           };


        }while(inputOk === false);


      ....
    }
```

Comment: Code dumps are not useful answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*. (And format code reasonably.)

Comment: Also note you've changed the range. You can't just change `year < 0` to `year > 0` to invert that condition. It's `year >= 0`.